# Ignore `wheel` event if `scroll` event fires too

Tags: javascript, scroll, mouseevent, mousewheel

I want to bind a `wheel`/`mousewheel` event to a container to trigger a "next page" effect, but I don't want it to fire if the mouse is on an element that is itself scrollable.

Is there any way to do this cleanly, or do I have to resort to checking every element in the range
[`event.target` — `this`] to see if it has `overflow:auto` or `overflow:scroll` and its `scrollHeight` is greater than its `offsetHeight`?

Comment: I don't think there's a method to do that, aside from the one you've already prescribed...

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can add a wheel/mousewheel event to the unscrollable element then call

```
event.stopPropagation()
```